# i want to parse data using SOAP and libxml2 so how it possible?

Tags: iphone, soap, libxml2

i have soap based Xml  using that soap message i want to perform libxml parsing also perform lazy loading so how can i perform it please any one have idea about it then please help me.

Comment: What have you done so far? This question is so broad it would be difficult to give you a good answer.

Comment: i have implemented both individually.

Comment: i can understand what you will say and if you have any kind of sample code regarding this task please give me it's really important for me at this moment.Thanks for response...

Comment: Instead of us writing your code, why not share what you've written and focus your question on what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this sample code:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtgr8-a3/
Hope it helps.

Comment: If you can share your xml schema I can create similar library for you to use. I have a home grown tool that generates this code. I can do it for you. I have used it to for over a dozen enterprise class very complicated apps and so far it has worked perfectly. You can go to http://www.mtgr8.com/Demo.html and request it.

Comment: The xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:setInfoResponse xmlns:ns1="xmlnstring"><return /data&gt;&lt;data&gt; [CDATA[2009]]&gt;&lt;/year&gt; &lt;season&gt;&lt;!/8.jpeg]]&gt;&lt;/collectionimage&gt;&lt;/data&gt;&lt;/information&gt;&lt;/root&gt;</return></ns1:setInfoResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: The tool only consume a WSDL/XSD only and not snippets. Please register at http://www.mtgr8.com/Demo.php with a brief description of your requirement. I will respond via email to with further info.